# Auto-Fill from on content type to another

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content type called **Point-of-Contacts**, basic info for a person. (~600 nodes)

I have another content type, like a form, that has a select list of all **Points-of-Contacts**.  When a user selects their desired **Point-of-Contact**, by name from the select list, I need the rest of the info of that **Point-of-Contact** to auto-fill text boxes on the form.

Any ideas?

NOTE: Using Drupal 7

Comment: ajax could consider an option

Comment: are you using custom form for **Points-of-Contacts** or the node content type form?!

Comment: I created a new content type for Points-of-Contact.

Though I may go back and import into as Drupal users in the People section.

Regardless, I still need the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

In my example I've created two content types with two custom fields in addition to your node reference field:

1. Node type: Point-of-Contact (machine name `points_of_contacts`)

   - **Text field:** To field one (machine name `field_to_field_one`)
   - **Text field:** To field two (machine name `field_to_field_two`)
2. Node type: Example (machine name `example`)

   - **Node reference:** Point-of-Contact (machine name `field_points_of_contacts`)
   - **Text field:** Field one (machine name `field_field_one`)
   - **Text field:** Field two (machine name `field_field_one`)

Then You need to create a custom module to alter node reference dropdown field to ajax dropdown with callback function.

First create custom module by following this [tutorial](http://drupal.org/node/1074360)

Second alter node reference field by implement this hook `hook_field_widget_form_alter`

```
function MODULE_NAME_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {

  if(isset($element['#field_name']) && $element['#field_name'] == 'field_points_of_contacts') {
    $element['#ajax'] = array(
      'callback' => 'MODULE_NAME_auto_fill_callback',
    );
  }
}
```

Third implement ajax callback function

```
function MODULE_NAME_auto_fill_callback(&$form, &$form_state) {

  $commands = array();

  if(isset($form_state['values']['field_points_of_contacts'])) {
    // get selected item/node from dropdown list
    $nid = $form_state['values']['field_points_of_contacts']['und'][0]['nid'];

    // load node by nid
    $node = node_load($nid);

    if($node) {

      if(isset($node->field_to_field_one['und'])) {
        // fill text field 
        // edit-field-field-one-und-0-value represent the generated html id of the text field 
        $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('#edit-field-field-one-und-0-value', 'val', array($node->field_to_field_one['und'][0]['value']));  
      }        

      if(isset($node->field_to_field_two['und'])) {
        // fill text field 
        // edit-field-field-two-und-0-value represent the generated html id of the text field 
        $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('#edit-field-field-two-und-0-value', 'val', array($node->field_to_field_two['und'][0]['value']));  
      }
    }
  }

  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

**Note:** change `MODULE_NAME` to your desirable module name.

Comment: Wow, I'm going to try this out now...thx!  I will post feedback soon.

Answer (score 0):

It must be late now but there is a module called [Entity Reference Autofill](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autofill) that can solve this issue.