# auto complete fields from selection

Tags: entities

I have taxonomy term with 2 fields: a and b. I have two taxonomy terms.

- term1: a1 and b1
- term2: a2 and b2

I have a content type with 3 fields; the first one is from a selected list from the taxonomy terms (term reference). When I choose the first field, I need that the related taxonomy terms appear on the second and third fields.
For example, if I choose term2, I need that the terms a2 and b2 appear automatically in the other fields.

Is it possible?

Comment: Do I have to use tokens?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if somebody are interested in it I've found this post that solve my question:

[Auto-Fill from on content type to another](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70452/auto-fill-from-on-content-type-to-another)