# autofill from taxonomy term fields

Tags: 7, entities, ajax

I'm trying to connect a field of a taxonomy term to a field in a content type, something like this:

[Auto-Fill from on content type to another](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70452/auto-fill-from-on-content-type-to-another/85075#85075)

I tried this on a node and it's working, but now I have some problems with the taxonomy term, is for this part?

```
// load node by nid
$node = node_load($nid);
```

Do I have to specify here the taxonomy? but I really don't know what to put in...

the field in content type is "field_descrizione_01" with empty field "field_udm"
the field with the data in the taxonomy terms is "field_udm_ti"

I've made this code (based on the link one):

```
/**
* Implements hook_field_widget_form_alter().
*/

function collegamento_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {

  if(isset($element['#field_name']) && $element['#field_name'] == 'field_descrizione_01') {
    $element['#ajax'] = array(
      'callback' => 'collegamento_auto_fill_callback',
    );
  }
}

function collegamento_auto_fill_callback(&$form, &$form_state) {

  $commands = array();

  if(isset($form_state['values']['field_descrizione_01'])) {
    // get selected item/node from dropdown list
    $nid = $form_state['values']['field_descrizione_01']['und'][0]['nid'];

    // load node by nid
    $node = node_load($nid);

    if($node) {

      if(isset($node->field_udm_ti['und'])) {
        // fill text field 
        $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('#edit-field-udm', 'val', array($node->field_udm_ti['und'][0]['value']));  
      }        



    }
  }

  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

Comment: Hello. Please post actual code you are using. We cannot reliably guess what changes you made already to make it work with taxonomy.

Comment: hello! i've posted it above

Comment: Maybe I've found the problem, I've used the field collection module, I've tried to change the #edit-field-udm part but it's still not working...
Somebody knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load a taxonomy term using [taxonomy_term_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7)

This should get you on the right track.

Comment: Hello, thanks.
I've tried to change $node = node_load($nid); in $node = taxonomy_term_load($nid); but not working. Do I have to change other terms?